# Google Apps Script to find out if a Student turned in an assignment late in Google Classroom

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classroom

For a Google Apps Script that I am developing, I need to filter out the Student submissions that were turned in late to lower their grade.

From Google's documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/list#LateValues) and [here](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/list) I a presupposing that this is gotten by using Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.StudentSubmissions.list but I do not know how to apply the late parameter to the list that comes out so as to only get the ones who turned the assignment in late.

```
function onlyLate(){
   var courseId = ID;
   var courseWorkId = ID;
   var la = {"late":"LATE_ONLY"};
   var lat = Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.StudentSubmissions.list(courseId, courseWorkId, la);
   Logger.log(lat);

   for (i = 0; i < lat.length; i++) {
      // lower grades here
   }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you need to pass the `Enum` value, but there doesn't appear to be a way to access the `Enum` values from the Apps Script `Classroom` advanced service (e.g. there isn't a `Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.Late.LATE_ONLY`). So if passing the string doesn't work, then you need to filter the collection

Answer (score 0):

Per the [API spec](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/list), you need to provide the appropriate [`Enum`](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/list#LateValues) value (which is not necessarily a `String` value). If passing the optional arguments to `list` of `{late: 'LATE_ONLY'}` does not work, then you will need to filter the output (which may be several pages long).

Note: you might try `late: "true"`, as the [Python client library's Google Classroom documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/classroom/v1/python/latest/classroom_v1.courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions.html#list) indicates that the parameter is the string of the desired lateness:

> **`late`**: `string`, Requested lateness value. If specified, returned student submissions are restricted by the requested value. If unspecified, submissions are returned regardless of `late` value.

```
function getAllLateSubmissionsByFiltering_(courseId, assignmentId) {
  const options = {
    // late: "LATE_ONLY"
    // or perhaps
    // late: "true"
  };
  const results = [];

  // Collect all results, not just those from the first page.
  do {
    var search = Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.StudentSubmissions.list(courseId, assignmentId, options);
    options.pageToken = search.nextPageToken;
    if (search.studentSubmissions && search.studentSubmissions.length)
      Array.prototype.push.apply(results, search.studentSubmissions);
  } while(options.pageToken);

  // Return only the results that were actually submitted late.
  return results.filter(function (studentSub) {
    studentSub.late === true;
  });
}
```

References:

- [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: I put precise info in the var search ( var search = Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.StudentSubmissions.list(8322717457, 18556522095, options); ) and when I uncommented late: "true" the error Invalid value at 'late' (TYPE_ENUM), "true" came out. Uncommenting late: "LATE_ONLY"  gave no errors, but the array results remained empty. I also tried studentSub.late === false;  just to see if the opposite would work, and still the array remained empty.

Comment: @JasonJurotich Looks like an issue with the client library then - I wasn't able to find the enums anywhere in its implementation (Compare to `SpreadsheetApp.Direction`). Maybe try various `int` values to see if anything works - e.g. `0` could be like omitting it, `1` might be "LATE_ONLY", … Also try as `true`/`false`. If you request the `"NOT_LATE_ONLY"` or unspecified versions, do you get values in the search? If not, please ensure you have the proper course and coursework ids - we've all made that oops before (though I would expect the API to throw a 401/403/500/other error in that case).